# FOR UPDATE doesn't seem to lock the row in MySql InnoDB

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, innodb, rowlocking

MySql = v5.6

Table engine = InnoDB

I have one mysql cli open. I run:

`START TRANSACTION;`

`SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE;`

I then have a second cli open and run:

`SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE id=1;`

I expected it to wait until I either committed or rolled back the first transaction but it doesn't, it just brings back the row straight away as if no row-locking had occurred.

I did another test where I updated a `status` field in the first cli and I couldn't see that change in the 2nd cli until I committed the transaction, proving the transactions are actually working.

Am I misunderstanding `FOR UPDATE` or doing something wrong?

**update:**

Needed `FOR UPDATE` on the 2nd `SELECT` query

Comment: It is possible to read when table are locked and select is read function

Comment: @Rafiq I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: you can see this 
document http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking/

Comment: @Rafiq - _table_ locking does not seem to be relevant to this question.  _Row_ locking is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That action you saw is valid.  With "MVCC", different connections can see different versions on the row(s).

The first connection grabbed a type of lock that prevents *writes*, but not *reads*.  If the second connection had done `FOR UPDATE` or `INSERT` or other "write" type of operation, it would have been either delayed waiting for the lock to be released, or deadlocked.  (A deadlock would require other locks going on also.)

**Common Pattern**

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE; -- the row(s) you will update in this transaction
miscellany work
UPDATE...;  -- those row(s).
COMMIT;
```

If two threads are running that code at the "same" time on the same row(s), the second one will stalled at the `SELECT..FOR UPDATE`.  After the first thread finished, the `SELECT` will run, getting the new values.  All is well.

Meanwhile, other threads can `SELECT` (without for update) and get some value.  Think of these threads as getting the value before or after the transaction, depending on the exact timing of all the threads.  The important thing is that these 'other' threads will see a *consistent* view of the data -- either *none* of the updates in that transaction have been applied, or *all* have been applied.  This is what "Atomic" means.

Comment: Thanks Rick. Is there such a thing as a READ lock? Basically the table holds queued items and I have multiple threads processing them - I don't want one item to be processed twice.

Is there a MySql pattern for this?

Comment: `FOR UPDATE` allows reading, but prevents writing.  I'll add to my answer in a minute.

Comment: Thank you! The key bit I was missing is the 2nd `SELECT` query must also use `FOR UPDATE`. This works as expected now.

Comment: But they do need to be enclosed in transaction? or there is another way?